# Bit manipulation inside a char array

Tags: c, char, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm writing a function to set/unset bits in an unsigned char array. I've been given the following instructions.

> In this task, bit 0 is the most significant bit. It is also assumed
> that unsigned char is exactly 8 bits (1 byte). Thus, for example, bit
> 8 is a leftmost bit in second unsigned char byte and bit 17 is the
> second highest bit in the third unsigned char byte. Thus, examining
> the number 170 (0xAA hexadecimal format, 10101010 in binary), the most
> significant bit, ie bit 0 has a value of 1.

based on that, I wrote the following.

```
/* NOTE:
 * -----------
 * The parameter binary data (const unsigned char*) in all the functions 
 * below is likely to hold more than 8 bits. You should take this into 
 * account when implementing your functions.
 */

/* DESCRIPTION:
 * ------------
 * The function sets a bit with index i as active (1) in the parameter
 * binary data.
 *
 * PARAMETERS:
 * ------------
 * unsigned char* data: an array of binary data.
 * int i: the index of the bit which to set as active (1).
 *
 * RETURNS:
 * ------------
 * Nothing.
 *
 */
void op_bit_set(unsigned char *data, int i)
{
    data[i/32] |= 1 << (i%32); 
}

/* DESCRIPTION:
 * ------------
 * The function sets a bit with index i as inactive (0) in the parameter
 * binary data.
 *
 * PARAMETERS:
 * ------------
 * unsigned char* data: an array of binary data.
 * int i: the index of the bit which to set as active (1).
 *
 * RETURNS:
 * ------------
 * Nothing.
 *
 */

void op_bit_unset(unsigned char *data, int i)
{
     data[i/32] &= ~(1 << (i%32)); 
}
```

When I test it with the given data, my answer is wrong.

```
unsigned char arr[2] = {0, 0};
 op_bit_set(arr, 0);

 *** Testing your op_bit_set function.. 
 At first arr[0] == 0x00 and arr[1] == 0x00 
 Setting bit 0 arr[0] is 0x01, should be 0x80 
 arr[1] is 0x00, should be 0x00
```

I based my answer on what I read here: [http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syllabus/1-C-intro/bit-array.html](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/255/Syllabus/1-C-intro/bit-array.html)

Comment: `i/32` should be `i/8`.

Comment: And `i % 32` should be `i % 8`

Comment: You use `unsigned char`, but then treat is as a `uint32_t`, with 32 bits of contents. If it is supposed to be using `unsigned char`, then all the 32 should be 8.

Comment: - and the bit offset to shift with should be reversed (7-(i%8)) since the most significant bit has the lowest index here.

Comment: The code you copied from uses `unsigned int` arrays, not `unsigned char` arrays.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError that was what I missed, I had tried it with 8, but it didn't work. I guess I forgot about the reversed bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thomas mentioned, you are using an unsigned char which has 8 bits. So your logic for determining the index and the bit number should use 8 instead of 32.

Also, since the most significant bit is the left most bit, you have to shift right 0x80(or 128) by i which gives you a mask for the specific bit that you want to set/unset.

In the end the code should look like this.

```
void op_bit_set(unsigned char *data, int i)
{
    data[i/8] |= 0x80 >> (i%8); 
}

void op_bit_unset(unsigned char *data, int i)
{
     data[i/8] &= ~(0x80 >> (i%8)); 
}
```